# Inconsistent ParseExeption with Data Format in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a simple Util method to convert a `String` in Java to `util.Date`. What I am not able to figure out is why the method works for the first input, and fails for the second one, given that the inputs are identical:

Code:

```
package util;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class StringToDate {

    public Date getDateFromString(String strDate, String dateFormat) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        Date date = null;

        try {

            date = df.parse(strDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(date);

        return date;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        StringToDate s2d = new StringToDate();

        s2d.getDateFromString("12-18-11, 10:36 AM","MM-dd-yy, hh:mm a");
        s2d.getDateFromString("02-04-12, 01:17 PM","MM-dd-yy, hh:mm a");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sun Dec 18 10:36:00 CET 2011
null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02-04-12, 01:17 PM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at util.StringToDate.getDateFromString(StringToDate.java:17)
    at util.StringToDate.main(StringToDate.java:33)
```

Logically, the output should've been `Sat Feb 04 13:17:00 CET 2012` going by the first output. Why is the `ParseException` being thrown?

**EDIT**: The following two lines work correctly:

```
s2d.getDateFromString("02-04-12", "MM-dd-yy");
s2d.getDateFromString("01:17 PM", "hh:mm a");
```

Output:

```
Sat Feb 04 00:00:00 CET 2012
Thu Jan 01 13:17:00 CET 1970
```

But the exception happens when I try to parse both date and time together.

Comment: I'm confused -- It works fine for me.

Comment: Me too - what culture are you in? Thanks for including a short but complete program, mind you :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't get what you mean by "what culture are you in?", but thanks for the compliment! Does the program work fine for you? I'm using JDK 1.6 (1.6.0.11). I tried Eclipse, and even the classic command-prompt route of running the above [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html). Still, same exception; same inconsistency. Help!

Comment: @SNag: I mean what's the default locale of your system? And yes, the program works fine for me - admittedly using Java 7, but I doubt that that's the problem.

Comment: Can you update your JRE and try again?

Comment: @SNag: If you add `System.out.println(java.util.Locale.getDefault());`, what does it print out for you? For example, I use a U.S. English locale, so it prints `en_US` for me. This can affect the meaning of `AM` and `PM`; it's possible that your locale uses `AM` for A.M., but something other than `PM` for P.M. (If that *is* the problem, then you can fix it by adding `java.util.Locale.US` as a second argument to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor, to force a U.S. interpretation of `AM` and `PM`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: My system's default locale shows up as "en_US". Does that have anything to do with the `ParseException`?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I tried adding the `java.util.Locale.US` argument to `SimpleDateFormat`; no effect. What's worse is that I'm able to individually parse the date part and time part, but not both together (see edit in question).

Comment: @SNag: That's very strange...

Comment: @SNag: And what's your default time zone? I wouldn't *expect* that to mess it up, but...

Comment: @JonSkeet: As @LukeWoodward pointed out below, there was a foreign (invisible) character in the date string. I'm sorry I overlooked a seemingly obvious hint! Eclipse did not show it, but trying to run the program through command prompt clearly outputs `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02-04-12,-á01:17 PM"`. I should've paid attention! Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a non-breaking space, or some other Unicode space character, somewhere in either your date string or format mask?

I was able to reproduce your error if I replaced one of the spaces in the second of your date strings with a non-breaking space, such as [Unicode character 160](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm).

Comment: Excellent catch!! Yes, that was it! Oh, my! The date string in the program above was actually copied from an external text that I was trying to parse. How can eliminate such non-breaking spaces, and replace them with actual white space?

Comment: +1 Because now I can go on with my life. I would have not been able to sleep until I got to know what was really going on here :)

Comment: Found what I was looking for: `cleanString = dirtyString.replace("\u00a0","")` or `cleanString = dirtyString.replace("&nbsp;","")` eliminates the parse-exception-causing **&nbsp;** ! :)